# Repair/add subfloor plank patch

Tags: subfloor

[image]

what is the best way to repair this?
the joist is about 24" apart here. what is the best way to add a piece of plank and support it from the joist?

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of hard to see the context here, but I'd guess the best way would be to get rid of all the pieces of planks and miscellaneous bits on the right side until you can get to the next joist on the right.

Then cut the existing plank(s) so that they overlap half of the joists on the left and then attach new planks to use the other half of the joists... The "seam" for the old, existing planks and the new, replacement planks will be centered over the joists.

Similar to this photo:
[image]
Except in the photo they're replacing the sub-floor around a toilet. Notice how the joists are half-exposed on either end of the cut out area. In your case, you'd fit the planks into the cut out area and screw them into the joists.

If you're not comfortable splitting the joists like that, you have a couple of other options:

- You could glue and screw boards along the existing joists to provide
  additional surface to attach the floor planks to. This is known as
  "sistering" the joists. It's not too hard to do, but may be kind of
  "over-kill" in this situation.
- If you can remove the whole plank from wall-to-wall and replace it,
  that may be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are better off adding a doubler to the joists on both ends...this is the standard way it's done. Achieve this using bugle screws on the doubler.

Otherwise, the fastening method for boards/planks will cause them to split as the fastener will be too close to the end of the timber.

Also, predrill holes if it's an old hardwood plank or it will split when fastener is inserted.

I prefer to countersink head 3mm down below surface and screw off replacement boards rather than nail, however that's up to you.

Definitely best use minimum of 3 joists coverage for replacement plank length if tongue and groove.